# Generating leaflet map in a popup

Tags: leaflet

I'm generating the leaflet map in a popup by a click event, with the code:

```
mymap = L.map('mapdiv').setView([center.lat, center.long], zoom);
```

However, if I close the popup and click again to generate a new map, I get the error:

> Map container is already initialized

How should I generate the map the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should destroy the map when the pop-up is closed. See the `remove()` method of `L.Map`. e.g.

```
var mymap;
popup.on('open', function(){
  mymap = L.map( /* etc */ );
});

popup.on('close', function(){
  mymap.remove();
});
```